# Сжатие раздела C

Tags: windows, файлы, windows-10, файловая-система, диск

Я хочу поставить linux рядом с windows 10. Понимаю, что для этого надо сжать диск C. На нём 52 гб свободного места, но компьютер даёт сжать его только на 18 гб. Я понимаю, что тут виноваты эти "точки восстановления". Я отключил защиту системы. Я удалил все точки восстановления. Я отключил гибернацию. Я дефрагментировал диск. Это не помогло. Можете видеть на картинке. Что ещё я упустил? Сжимать диск с помощью minitool я не собираюсь.

[[image: Мой экран после завершения всех операций1]

Comment: *Сжимать диск с помощью minitool я не собираюсь.* - почему?

Comment: Виртуальная машина, на которой я пробовал, после этого сломалась. Просто синий экран был

Comment: Если вы про [этот](https://www.partitionwizard.com/) minitool, то много раз им пользовался и ничего не ломалось. Опишите алгоритм действий, который привёл к бсоду, видимо, вы что-то не так сделали

Comment: Открывай маннитол, выбираю disk1, раздел C. Потом жму move/resize и сжимаю раздел. Он просит перезагрузить компьютер, и запускается в виде командной строки. Сжимает. Ещё раз перезагружается. Нет обоев. Меню пуск не работает. Выскакивают сообщения об ошибках.

Comment: Правда, я пользовался динамическим диском, 6адо попробовать статический

Comment: Да, логичная идея. Я им пользовался на реальной системе, а не виртулке, если что. Так что может быть проблема в ней, если всё правильно делаете

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри папки:

1. C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution - папка куда винда складывает обновы обычно много хлама там. особенно в папке "C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download"
2. C:\Windows\Temp - временные файлы винды
3. C:\Users*все_что_есть*\AppData\Local\Temp - временные файлы пользователей
4. По классике почистить корзину ;)

Comment: Это, конечно, осводит место на диске, но проблему с неперемещаемыми файлами в общем случае не решит

Comment: на сколько я помню, ему для сжатия нужно свободное место в % от диска. Найти пруф с ходу не получилось. мб попозже скину. Поэтому я бы освободил максимально место и попробовал сжать еще.

Comment: Тут проблема в том, что есть раздел `___xxxx___yyy_____zzzz__`, а надо сделать `xxxxyyyzzzz_____________`, где `x|y|z` - данные, `_` - свободное место, и надо поставить в пустое место новый раздел с линуксом

Comment: а как на счет такого алгоритма: 1. сделать бекап через Acronis True Image 2. форматнуть диск  3. разбить диск на два логических 4. потом восстановить бекап на один из логических дисков и накатить Linux на другой?

Comment: Напишите об этом в ответе или в комментарии к автору, не знаю его намерений :)